# AS3-Having a mouse click affect object in an array's timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe-flash-cs3

I'm going crazy with this. I have a few bears on the stage and have listed them in an array. I want them to change their animation frame when clicked as long as they are not on the "down" animation frame to begin with. Below is the code. The problem occurs below the //check if they get hit line.

```
 //put the bears in an array
var bearsArray: Array = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<numChildren;i++) {
    if (getChildAt (i) is bear_mc) {
        bearsArray.push(getChildAt(i));
    }
}

//move them up and down
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,upAndDown);
function upAndDown(event:Event){
    if (Math.random() < 0.02){
        var randomBear = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
            bearsArray[randomBear].gotoAndPlay("popup");
    }
}


//check if they get hit 
for (var j:int = 0; j < bearsArray.length; j++){
    bearsArray[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitBears);
}

function hitBears(e:MouseEvent){
    for (var k: int=0; k<numChildren; k++){
        if (bearsArray[k].currentFrame != "down"){
            trace("clicked"); 
            bearsArray[k].gotoAndPlay("surprised");
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*currentFrame* returns an integer, not string. If you want to use string, you have to use *currentFrameLabel* or *currentLabel*.

EDIT: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentLabel

If you want to control only one bear, remember that you don't need to cycle through them (actually that would serve no purpose as you would be checking every one of them). The better (and correct) approach would be this:

```
function hitBears(e:MouseEvent){
    var bear:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
    if(bear.currentLabel != "down") { //or currentFrameLabel, depends how your mc is set up
        trace("clicked");
        bear.gotoAndPlay("surprised");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to currentFrameLabel, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to control all the bears or only the clicked on? I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve and what exactly is happening now.

Comment: Just the bear that is being clicked on and only if it is not already in the "down" frame of it's animation. Essentially I'm making a whack-a-mole-like game for my kid.

As for what it is doing right now, the "clicked" trace statement isn't even running when a bear is clicked and it's definitely not changing animation frames.

Comment: Actually let me add, the clicked trace statement does execute, but it is seemingly random. It is hard to tell why it does it sometimes and not others.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but this has the exact same results as it did before :( The trace function still randomly executed.

Comment: Put the trace outside of the condition (right over *var bear:MovieClip = ...*). Does it execute now every time?

Comment: Then there must be something with your references, I can't explain it anyhow else. Check whether your array indeed contains all the bears and whether it has the correct length.

Comment: There are 9 total bears, I changed it to say:
for (var i=0; i<10;i++) {
and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by checking a hittest with the mouse instead of just checking the click. That works for some reason.